# Get existing audio video stream in browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I am using js library which call getUserMedia internally, I want to get hold of the stream object that already has been started.

But library doesn't expose it.

So is there a way to get the already started stream from underlying navigator object without calling the getUserMedia method?

Comment: Why don't you want to call getUserMedia again?

Comment: @jib As it will trigger the browser permission popup specifically in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `getUserMedia` again with the same constraints while the stream is live.

`getUserMedia` in Firefox [no longer](https://bugzil.la/1270572) prompts for permission to devices you're already currently actively using. In that case, it's equivalent to `let stream2 = stream.clone();`.

This behavior has been ratified in the [MediaCapture spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia()):

> For the origin identified by originIdentifier, request permission for use of the devices, while considering all devices attached to a live MediaStreamTrack in the current browsing context to have permission status "granted", resulting in a set of provided media.